# Google InApp Billing- Testing In-app subscription purchases on an android emulator devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, in-app-billing

I am new to the implementation of Google's Billing library and using this system to make subscriptions inside my app. I would like to know whether it is possible to do in-app billing/purchase and test my application on an Android Emulator devices? I want to do some functional testing of my application on multiple emulators. Later on I would like to test the 'in-app billing' on a real device.

Can you please suggest on how to test In-App Purchase on emulator devices?

Answer (score 0):

You Should have Emulator with Google Play services Enabled and there you can Login in Google Account / Google Play Store as publisher's account.

You can try that.

Comment: Thanks for the information !!! The purchase made in an emulator device will be a Sandbox Purchase or it will be a real purchase . Can you please confirm?

Comment: When I was working on it it was charging 1 INR and reverting it back after successful transaction. It may be the same thing till now. I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the update !!! Please let me know if you any other updates from any of your resources